# GIT merge, branches

Tags: git

I have a small question for the use of versioning program git
In my company we have 3 git branches:

- Working
- Test
- Production

When I have made changes in some files, I use the git such:

1. I create a new temporary branch: git branch mywork
2. Stager my changed files: git add testnow.txt
3. Commiting to my local repository: git commit -m "adding new features" git push
4. `git checkout Working`
5. `git merge mywork`
6. `git branch -d mywork`
7. `git push` (push to remote repository)

The question is whether one should make a pull  between paragraphs 4 and 5 - The pull make  my local repository or my branch Mywork updated .??. (Can anyone explain what is happening here and why)?

Comment: First of all, `git branch mywork` creates the branch but doesn't switch to it. So when you add and commit after that, you're doing it in whatever branch you were in before.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking whether you should do the following between steps 4 and 5:

```
git pull origin Working
```

If you do this extra step, then your local `Working` branch will get updated to the latest state on the remote server.  This matters, because you usually want to be working with the latest state of your application code.

If you *don't* do this extra pull step, then it increases the likelihood that there could be conflicts when you go to reconcile your local `Working` branch with what is on the remote.  One typical way you would bring your local `Working` into the remote would be via a pull request.  If you don't pull, then there is a greater chance of merge conflicts later on.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking to take a pull after step 4,

So when you should take pull after step 4 so that your `Working` branch gets updated. After it, you can merge your `mywork` branch in it .

If you don't want to take the pull & merge it directly in your local branch(Working) & then push , then the chances of conflicts increase. Also, you cannot use/test the updated branch at this point.

So, it is better to take the pull first.

Ideally, you should follow the below process:

```
1. git checkout Working
2. git pull
3. git checkout -b mybranch
4. make changes in the local branch
5. git add .
6. git commit -m "commit message"
7. git push origin mybranch
8. Send a pull request 
9. Make the changes as per the code review
10.Git add & commit & push
11.git checkout working
12.git merge mybranch
13.git push origin working
14.git push origin --delete mybranch
15.git branch -d mybranch
```